# Linux distros support UEFI & GPT?

Tags: linux, uefi

Any idea about the popular Linux distros support GPT and can **be installed with UEFI model from the get-go**?

Comment: Might be relevant: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40775/12779 At the moment I only know of Fedora 17 that supports the necessary kernel configuration by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [UEFI forums](http://www.uefi.org/about/) discuss:

> Q:    When will products using UEFI technology be available in the market place?
>
> A:    Platforms using the existing EFI 1.10 specification are already in the market place. Platforms using the UEFI specification will enter the market as the specification is developed by the Forum.

Most of Linux distributions already supports UEFI, it comes from the last Linux kernel releases. However, you can also use Grub to boot from UEFI BIOS, as is explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting).
You can find more information about how to boot Linux from a UEFI BIOS and which bootloaders also supports UEFI [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EFIBootLoaders).